# Zeros in the middle of figures number

Tags: numbering

I have a little issue with the figure numbering. As long as I put toc depth = 3 When I set a figure in the first section for example LaTex leaves a 0 in the middle.

See the example of a figure in the first section

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-fr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}{}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}

\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

xxxx

\section{xxxxx}

xxxxx

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=5cm]{Figuras/1_2_circ_op_tot.png}
\caption{Operativa (año móvil) y circulante (a diciembre) en relación al PIB}
\label{fig:1_2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you use `article` class or `book`? Apparently your `\thefigure` command is defined as `\thesection.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{figure}` etc, but that's only a guess -- posting such a fragment of code is not really useful. Please provide the minimal document that still has this issue

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable ...

Comment: There is a `\end{document}` missing. And the 'error' is `\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}` -- you don't have a subsection yet, so the counter is `0` and this is added to the figure number output. Either add a subsection or say `\counterwithin{figure}{section}` rather.  The additional `{}` after `\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}` is wrong anyway, but it does no harm here!

Comment: I find it also inconsistent to number tables according to sections but figures according according to subsections

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I have subsections also, how can I deal with both numbering. In subsection is okay the numbering but in sections I get that 0's in the middle. Thanks for your support and apologies for my rudimentary coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following instruction after `\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}`:

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{%
   \ifnum\value{subsection}=0{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}%
   \else{\thesubsection.\arabic{figure}}\fi}
```

This code defines the `\thefigure` macro to prefix the `figure` counter with just the section number if the value of the `subsection` counter is `0`, i.e., after `\section` but before `\subsection` has been executed.

Answer (score 1):

see if this can help:

```
%    \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}

    \counterwithin{figure}{section}
                \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection-\arabic{figure}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{
    \ifnum\value{section}=0\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}}\fi
                            }
```

you can easy lover the level of figure numbering (from chapter to section and from section to subsection:

```
%    \renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}

    \counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
                \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesubsection-\arabic{figure}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{
    \ifnum\value{subsection}=0\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection-\arabic{figure}}\fi
                            }
```

**edit:**
in case of such numbering i suggest to use `-` as separator before figure number. this help you distinguish it from number of chapter and section or section and subsection when on of them is omitted.